# C Borland Compiler Error

Tags: c, borland-c

Back to basics with Borland C Compiler. I keep getting the following message and it is driving me crazy as I cannot find where the semi colon should go or why it is expected

```
>bcc32 -v- -w -O1 oddEven.c
Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
oddEven.c:
Error E2378 oddEven.c 16: For statement missing ; in function main()
*** 1 errors in Compile ***
>Exit code: 1
```

Here is my code, Thanks for any help in advance

```
/* Program to check if a given integer between 1 and 100 is odd or even
 Date: 09/10/2015 */


#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int input;

    printf("\nPlease Enter A Number Between 1 and 100\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("\nYou Entered %d\n", input);

    //for loop used for error handling
    for(input > 0 && input < 101)
    {

            if(input <= 0 && input > 100)

                {
                  printf("Error!! Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 100");

                 }//end if 1


            //modulo 2 to check for even divisibility 
            if(input % 2 == 0)
                {
                    printf("\n %d is EVEN", input);
                }//end if 2

            else
                {
                    printf("\n %d is ODD", input);
                }//end else

    }//end for loop

        getchar();
        getchar();

}//end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for(input > 0 && input < 101)
```

is invalid syntax. It should be

```
while(input > 0 && input < 101)
```

but then you have an infinite loop on entering anything valid. It should probably be an `if`, but then, no error message is printed when the user enters an invalid number. You should then move

```
if(input <= 0 && input > 100)
{
    printf("Error!! Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 100");
}//end if 1
```

outside the `if`.

There are a lot of other problems as well. I suggest you read a good C book.

**Fixed Code:**

```
/* Note how this code is indented and looks clean */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) /* Valid signature of main */
{
    int input, c; /* Note the extra variable */

    printf("\nPlease Enter A Number Between 1 and 100\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("\nYou Entered %d\n", input);

    if(input <= 0 || input > 100) /* Note the use of || instead of && */
    {
        printf("Error!! Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 100 \n");
    }
    else /* Note the else */
    {
        if(input % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n %d is EVEN \n", input);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n %d is ODD \n", input);
        }
    }

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); /* Clear the stdin */
    getchar(); /* Wait for a character */
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Got rid of the for loop. Moved the error handling if statement under the scanf function and wrapped the first half of the code in a do while loop. Works just fine. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

```
for(input > 0 && input < 101)
```

This has problem . You can write like this -

```
for( ; (input > 0 )&& (input < 101) ;)
```